# DataTable not showing JSON data

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, datatable

```
            var table = $('#datatables').DataTable({
                ajax: {
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetGrid","Vibrant", new { Area = "Marketing" })',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: {
                        //filters here
                        columns: null,
                        filter: function () { return _filter; },
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log("success", data);
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        console.log("error", data);
                    }
                },
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                responsive: true,
                pagingType: 'full_numbers',
                language: {
                    search: "_INPUT_",
                    searchPlaceholder: "Search records",
                },
                columns: [
                    { "data": "ID"},
                    { "data": "PreviewID"},
                    { "data": "EPCElement"},
                    { "data": "Vibrant"}
                ],
```

method successfully returns data but the DataTable won't display it.

```
            initialList = (from pjob in _db.PropertyJobs
                       select new SendVibrantOrderGridVM
                       {
                           ID = pjob.ID,
                           PreviewID = pjob.PreviewID,
                           EPCElement = pjob.EPCElement ,
                           Vibrant = pjob.Vibrant 
                       }).ToList();
```

I am trying to populate my DataTable with the JSON Data I'd be getting within a call method.

This is a sample data returned by the GetGrid method:

```
{"data":[{"ID":529,"PreviewID":999992349,"EPCElement":false,"Vibrant":false}],"draw":1,"page":1,"pages":113,"length":10,"recordsTotal":1126,"recordsFiltered":1126}
```

Comment: please take a look at : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1118363/GridView-with-Server-Side-Filtering-Sorting-and-Pa

Comment: and secondly look at browser console for any errors, was it working before ? what you recently added in the js?

Comment: There were no errors @EhsanSajjad

Comment: What element are you using for the DataTable? Check the ID of the table by viewing source, if you're using webforms the ID can get mangled by the WebForms engine. Please include some HTML for context.

Comment: and your method in form returns json right?

Comment: Please use `Chrome Developer Tools` -> `Network tab` to see the payload being returned by `GetGrid`. Please include that in your post.

Comment: Updated @mjwills